# In R stacked barplot with colors mapped according to variable

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I am just starting in R, and I'm stuck at the barplots.
I want to make a stacked barplot where the colors are chosen based on a variable.

My data looks lik this:

Thickness 
point 3   point 5 point 6 point 7 point 8 point 9 point 11
layer1  25  20  90  80  100 45  75
layer2  5   20  0   0   0   70  0
layer3  80  5   0   0   0   0   0

Type
    point 3 point 5 point 6 point 7 point 8 point 9 point 11
layer1  4   3   3   3   3   3   3
layer2  5   5   6   6   6   5   6
layer3  4   3   6   6   6   6   6

For each point there is a number of thickness `AL` that need to be stacked on top of each other, and the type `AL_col` indicates the color the stacked bars need to have.

My script:

```
col1<-c("green","brown","purple","black","yellow", "white")
barplot(Thickness, col=col1[Type])
```

Thanks!

## EDIT

I ll try to explain a bit better:
I have 10.000 locations, these are the points (as an example here above the points 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,  11)
These locations can consisist of 3 layers.
The layers differ in thickness and in the type of material.
What I am trying to do is:
for each point have a stacked barplot where the thickness of each layer can be seen.
And to see the type of material I want to use a color scheme. Which varies for each point.

Comment: In your definition of AL the number of points doesn't match the number of columns. Could you post R code generating AL  and AL_col?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard barplot does fine too, you just need to put your data in a matrix. Example:

```
    L <- data.frame(point = c(3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11), 
    layer1 = c(1, 25, 20, 90, 80, 100, 45),                  
    layer2 = c(5, 20, 0, 0, 0, 70, 0), 
    layer3 = c(80, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

    barplot(t(as.matrix(L)),col=c("blue","black","yellow","orange"))
```

[image]

Doing exactly what you want implies for loops:

```
    L <- data.frame(
            layer1 = c(25, 20, 90, 80, 100, 45),     
            layer2 = c(5, 20, 0, 0, 70, 0), 
            layer3 = c(80, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    rownames(L)<-c(3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

    AL_col <- matrix(c(
                4,3,3,3,3,3,
                5,5,6,6,6,5,
                4,3,6,6,6,6),ncol=6,byrow=TRUE)
    colnames(AL_col) <- c("point3","point5","point6","point7","point8","point9")
    rownames(AL_col) <- c("layer1","layer2","layer3")

    col1<-c("green","brown","purple","black","yellow", "white","blue")

    # the problem is then to make polygons corresponding to your colors

    maxHeight <- max(as.matrix(L) %*% rep(1,dim(L)[2]))
    widthPol <- 0.5
    plot(c(1-widthPol,dim(L)[1]+widthPol),c(0,maxHeight),type="n",xlab="Points",ylab="Height")

    for(iPoint in 1:6){
        currentY <- 0
        for(iLayer in 1:3){
            addedY <- L[iPoint,iLayer]
                if(addedY>0){
                    xs <- c(rep(iPoint-widthPol/2,2),rep(iPoint+widthPol/2,2))
                        ys <- c(0,addedY,addedY,0)
                        colPoly <- col1[AL_col[iLayer,iPoint]]
                        polygon(x=xs,y=ys+currentY,col=colPoly)
                        currentY <- currentY + addedY
                }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Again this is not what I ment. The plots above have layer 1 in blue, layer 2 in black and so on, for each bar
I ll try with a picture as example of what I am trying to do

Comment: Apperently I can add pictures because I am new: SO i ll try to put it in words...
So point 3, the first bar, would have black, yellow, black with a respective heigth of 25, 5, 80. 
Point 5, the second bar would have purple, black, purple with a respeative heigth of 20, 20, 5

Comment: The problem in your special case of color scheme is that L is very badly defined. You need to have one line per color. Ideally L could be transformed to meet that requirement as you don't need to keep "layer" info but unfortunately you have two times the same color in the same bar in your scheme, and that makes using the standard barplot impossible. Hence you have to do it by hand I'm afraid: you plot polygons one after the other ...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I just going to loop through the data, picking the colors for each bar seperate. I was hoping there was a better way of doing this

Comment: @llhameO doesn't this answer exactly your question now? Remember to up vote!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than base R graphics, perhaps use `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot)

AL <- data.frame(point = c(3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11), layer1 = c(1, 25, 20, 90, 80, 100, 45),
                 layer2 = c(5, 20, 0, 0, 0, 70, 0), layer3 = c(80, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
AL.m <- melt(AL, id.vars = "point")

col1<-c("green","brown","purple","black","yellow", "white")
barplot(AL, col=col1[AL_col])

ggplot(AL.m, aes(x = point, y = value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col1)
```

[image]

**EDIT after COMMENT**
Since there are only three layers, only the first three colors of col1 are used.
It is not clear to me what alternative coloring scheme you are seeking.

Comment: Thanks for your fast responds. But it's not what I ment. I would like the colors to match the value each layer in each point has with the AL_col. So point 3, the first bar, would have black, yellow, black with a respective heigth of 25, 5, 80.
Point 5, the second bar would have purple, black, purple with a respeative heigth of 20, 20, 5.
Is this possible to do?